# Accessing Request object in Apollo Server with ExpressJS

Tags: express, apollo, apollo-server

Is there any way of accessing the request object from the underlying express app in Apollo Server

Answer (score 2):

The context configuration parameter can be either an object, a function that returns the object, or a function that returns a promise to return the object. This function would get the HTTP request as a parameter, and could be defined like so:

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const something = getSomething(req)
    return { something }
  },
})

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' })

const { appPort } = serviceFunc.getAccessData()
app.listen({ port: appPort }, () => {
  console.log(`Express+Apollo Server on http://localhost:${appPort}/graphql`)
})
```

Thanks to [Eugene eugene1g](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1066)